# Can't upload asp.net mvc4 site to server 403 access forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, razor

Its my uni server using IIS and I'm one hundred per cent certain it has something to do with my web.config file. It's working locally but not when I try to upload it to the server. It was for a short time this morning but I can't think what I've changed. I looked up this question and added `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` but that is possibly in the wrong place (system.web instead of system.webserver?). It's using MVC4 with razor view engine. :-( This is the web.config file...

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DMEUqS_3iXfla4B1Gk5uvR6OD0V7DfHgGFeRHa3IUM0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using? Did you check the IIS manager settings to make sure that your application has permissions to any folders hosting your content? Are the handlers setup to properly serve the content that you expect? There's lots of IIS settings that can cause these issues.

Comment: Or did you try 'iisreset' as well as 'aspnet_regiis -ir'?